# How to get tableviewer row items?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, jface

I have a tableviewer inside a plugin with a view. The tableviewer has 5 columns. I need the data in the rows when I select the row. For example: when I select the row 1, the listener should store in a variable the data for column 1 row 1.

I have used this to get the data in the selected row but it returns the data for the first column only:

```
table.addListener(SWT.DefaultSelection, new Listener() {       
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
          TableItem[] selection = table.getSelection();
          for (int i = 0; i < selection.length; i++)
          {                 
          System.out.println(selection[i].getText());
          }                    
    }
  });
```

How to get the data in all the columns of the row?

Comment: You want to select single cells of your viewer?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503057/eclipse-rcp-how-to-select-a-single-cell-in-tableviewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TableViewer.addSelectionChangedListener`

```
viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
  @Override
  public void selectionChanged(final SelectionChangedEvent event)
  {
    IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection)event.getSelection();

    RowData rowData = (RowData)selection.getFirstElement();

    ....
  }
});
```

where `RowData` is your model object for the row